# Themeleaf and submit form POST

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

Mavens,

I am struggling to invoke a controller from Themeleaf.

My themeleaf code looks like:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/order}" modelAttribute="order" th:object="${order}"  method="POST">
                <div class="div">
                        <h5>Amount</h5>
                        <input type="text" class="input" th:field="*{amountValue}">
                    </div>

                <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Process Payment">
            </form>
```

My Controller Code is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/order", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public  ModelAndView processOrder(@ModelAttribute Order order) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        String accessToken = token();
        String paymentURL = null;
        if (accessToken != null) {
            paymentURL = placeOrder(accessToken, order);
            if (paymentURL != null) {
                modelAndView.addObject("orderReferenceNumber", paymentURL.substring(paymentURL.indexOf("=") + 1));
                modelAndView.addObject("paymentURL", paymentURL + "&slim=true");
                modelAndView.setViewName("paymentProcess");
                return modelAndView;
            }
        }
        return modelAndView;

    }
```

My Get method is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView doLogin(@RequestParam(value = "username", required = true) String username,
            @RequestParam(value = "password", required = true) String password) {
         ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        if (username != null && password != null) {
            if (username.equalsIgnoreCase("one") && password.equalsIgnoreCase("one")) {
                 modelAndView.addObject("order", new Order());
                 modelAndView.setViewName("index"); 
                 return modelAndView;
            }
        }
         modelAndView.setViewName("welcome"); 
         return modelAndView;
    }
```

Error on click of the button

```
Error resolving template [order], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [order], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: can you please add the GET controller method which returns the initial view which contains this form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes from how you populate your `ModelAndView` instance. Only when your two `if` clauses are matched, you set the name of the view with `modelAndView.setViewName("paymentProcess");`. That means for some executions (not matching your both conditionals), you don't set the name of the view at all and Spring MVC doesn't know which view to render and return to the user.

To fix this, make sure you always set a default/fallabck view to return in case the `if` conditions are both not `true`. Your code might override this view name but you have at least for each case a view to fallback on:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/order", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public  ModelAndView processOrder(@ModelAttribute Order order) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("yourDefaultViewName"); // this is the important line
    String accessToken = token();
    String paymentURL = null;
    if (accessToken != null) {
        paymentURL = placeOrder(accessToken, order);
        if (paymentURL != null) {
            modelAndView.addObject("orderReferenceNumber", paymentURL.substring(paymentURL.indexOf("=") + 1));
            modelAndView.addObject("paymentURL", paymentURL + "&slim=true");
            modelAndView.setViewName("paymentProcess");
            return modelAndView;
        }
    }
    return modelAndView;

}
```

Comment: thanks but i doubt that is the issue. In  my case the /order controller is not invoked only.

Comment: I tested it locally and without always setting a viewname I get the exact same error message like you. Could you please try it?

Comment: oh hell ya!.. that indeed was the issue. Thank u.